# Acentuação no CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, php-7

Olá, meus caros! A dúvida abaixo é bem *noob*, mas está queimando meus neurônios...

Instalei recentemente o CakePHP 4.2.8, PHP 7.4.9.

Estou caminhando no tutorial do CakePHP, e fiz um bake para uma das minhas tabelas no banco de dados. Como de praxe, tudo veio em inglês, e fui traduzindo os textos que serão exibidos para o usuário.

Ocorre que quando eu coloco um texto com acento, eles não são exibidos corretamente no navegador. Vamos usar como exemplo o template do index.php gerado pelo bake:

```
<h3><?= __('Estados da Federação') ?></h3>
```

Os acentos não são exibidos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu colocar as entidades HTML manualmente, funciona: `<h3><?= __('Estados da Federa&ccedil;&atilde;o') ?></h3>` é exibido corretamente.

Porém, se eu utilizar `h` ou sua versão por extenso, `htmlspecialchars`, continua aparecendo errado. Se eu usar `htmlentities` é ainda pior: `<h3><?= __(htmlentities('Estados da Federação')) ?></h3>` não exibe nada. O HTML final para o usuário aparece como `<h3></h3>` e eu fico com uma linha em branco.

Acho que não se trata de problema de *charset*, pois já pesquisei alguns guias na *web*, e todas configurações que encontrei já estão em UTF-8.

Alguém sabe como resolver o problema da acentuação sem ter que colocar as entidades HTML para todas as letras acentuadas? Eu tenho certeza de que essa é uma pergunta extremamente *noob*, mas estou me batendo com isso severamente.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Os robôs estão doidões...

Comment: Você está usando `__()` por que precisa de internacionalização? Se não precisar, remova. Por fim confira o encode do ser arquivo

Comment: @ErlonCharles Como eu disse, sou noob no cake e estou fazendo o tutorial. Vou testar pra ver se funciona sem isso.

Comment: Salve, meu caro @ErlonCharles! Tentei tirar a função ```__()```, mas não fez diferença nenhuma. O encode do arquivo está em UTF-8. Todas as configurações da aplicação no cake estão com UTF-8, e o HTML que é gerado para mim no navegador também tem, no cabeçalho, a tag ```meta``` para a codificação UTF-8.

Comment: Eu agora estou tentando upar para um servidor de teste e ver se é algo que está dando errado apenas no meu computador.

Comment: A propósito, QUE COMUNIDADE NOCIVA! Fiz uma pergunta simples e duas pessoas se deram o trabalho de dar dislike sem sequer tentar responder... Putz! Essa comunidade está pesando de cara para eu esquecer Cake e aprender o Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salve, comunidade nociva!

Descobri o problema! Evidentemente era um charset, mas não era do documento, nem do Cake, nem do banco de dados, nem do servidor (testei postar online em vez de testar apenas no Wamp na minha máquina), nem do navegador (cheguei a mudar a *meta tag* no documento HTML final aberto no meu navegador usando as ferramentas de desenvolvedor, e nada). Meu último teste antes de partir para o Laravel foi instalar o VSCode -- e, de fato, no VSCode a acentuação funcionou certinho. A questão era a codificação-padrão do Visual Studio 2019!

Ocorre que o Visual Studio (pelo menos até o 2019) não possui opção de codificação padrão, então foi necessário ajustar o arquivo `.editorconfig`. Abaixo da entrada `[*]` (que guarda as configurações a serem aplicadas a todos os arquivos), adicionei a seguinte linha:

```
[*]
[...outras configurações...]
charset = utf-8
```

E pronto. Mais uma vez, o dia foi salvo -- e não foi graças à comunidade tóxica do CakePHP BR. <3

Agora, Adeus. Só posto dúvidas sobre Cake no internacional.